# How to debug why WAN TCP/IP throughput is lower than expected?

Tags: tcp, tcpip, tcpdump

I'm trying to figure out why tcp/ip throughput between two hosts I control is much lower than expected.

Host A:  internet connectivity provided by Comcast (Residential) in Boston Metro -- can consistently achieve 100Mbps download from various well known sites (e.g. downloading Google Chrome)

Host B:  internet connectivity provided by Cogent; can consistently achieve near 100Mbps to and from various sites.

Test Connection:  Host A downloads a large file from B, via rsync/ssh on a non-standard port (22442) (i.e. `rsync --progress -e 'ssh -p 22442' ...` -- throughput is only around 2.5Mbps (292564 Bps)

Other clients (e.g a scratch EC2 instance) can achieve near 30 times throughput when attempting the same download from B

I've managed to capture statistics of the connection between A and B with tcptrace (attached below) but I'm not sure if anything seems wrong.

I imagine there is something on my end that needs tweaking, but I also have a slight suspicion about Comcast shaping traffic -- so before I start flailing around, I thought I would seek advice. What are some good next steps for me to try? Thanks in advance.

```
tcptrace -r -l -o1 dump.out
 1 arg remaining, starting with 'dump.out'
 Ostermann's tcptrace -- version 6.6.7 -- Thu Nov  4, 2004

 5763 packets seen, 5763 TCP packets traced
 elapsed wallclock time: 0:00:00.019828, 290649 pkts/sec analyzed
 trace file elapsed time: 0:00:18.655110
 TCP connection info:
 1 TCP connection traced:
 TCP connection 1:
    host a:        XXX.XXXX.XXX:41608
    host b:        XXX.XXXX.XXX:22442
    complete conn: RESET    (SYNs: 2)  (FINs: 1)
    first packet:  Sun May 26 14:48:52.923281 2013
    last packet:   Sun May 26 14:49:11.578391 2013
    elapsed time:  0:00:18.655110
    total packets: 5763
    filename:      dump.out
    a->b:                 b->a:
      total packets:          1946           total packets:          3817
      resets sent:              15           resets sent:               0
      ack pkts sent:          1930           ack pkts sent:          3817
      pure acks sent:         1874           pure acks sent:           35
      sack pkts sent:          228           sack pkts sent:            0
      dsack pkts sent:           0           dsack pkts sent:           0
      max sack blks/ack:         3           max sack blks/ack:         0
      unique bytes sent:      4100           unique bytes sent:   5457821
      actual data pkts:         55           actual data pkts:       3781
      actual data bytes:      4100           actual data bytes:   5457821
      rexmt data pkts:           0           rexmt data pkts:           0
      rexmt data bytes:          0           rexmt data bytes:          0
      zwnd probe pkts:           0           zwnd probe pkts:           0
      zwnd probe bytes:          0           zwnd probe bytes:          0
      outoforder pkts:           0           outoforder pkts:          23
      pushed data pkts:         55           pushed data pkts:         41
      SYN/FIN pkts sent:       1/1           SYN/FIN pkts sent:       1/0
      req 1323 ws/ts:          Y/Y           req 1323 ws/ts:          Y/Y
      adv wind scale:            7           adv wind scale:            7
      req sack:                  Y           req sack:                  Y
      sacks sent:              228           sacks sent:                0
      urgent data pkts:          0 pkts      urgent data pkts:          0 pkts
      urgent data bytes:         0 bytes     urgent data bytes:         0 bytes
      mss requested:          1460 bytes     mss requested:          1460 bytes
      max segm size:           712 bytes     max segm size:          1448 bytes
      min segm size:            16 bytes     min segm size:            21 bytes
      avg segm size:            74 bytes     avg segm size:          1443 bytes
      max win adv:          301184 bytes     max win adv:           21632 bytes
      min win adv:            5888 bytes     min win adv:           14592 bytes
      zero win adv:              0 times     zero win adv:              0 times
      avg win adv:          269168 bytes     avg win adv:           21615 bytes
      initial window:           20 bytes     initial window:           21 bytes
      initial window:            1 pkts      initial window:            1 pkts
      ttl stream length:      4101 bytes     ttl stream length:        NA
      missed data:               1 bytes     missed data:              NA
      truncated data:            0 bytes     truncated data:            0 bytes
      truncated packets:         0 pkts      truncated packets:         0 pkts
      data xmit time:       18.128 secs      data xmit time:       18.527 secs
      idletime max:         5206.5 ms        idletime max:         5285.9 ms
      throughput:              220 Bps       throughput:           292564 Bps

      RTT samples:              57           RTT samples:            1661
      RTT min:                59.0 ms        RTT min:                 0.0 ms
      RTT max:               106.1 ms        RTT max:                40.1 ms
      RTT avg:                77.2 ms        RTT avg:                 1.4 ms
      RTT stdev:              17.2 ms        RTT stdev:               7.1 ms

      RTT from 3WHS:          60.0 ms        RTT from 3WHS:           0.0 ms

      RTT full_sz smpls:         2           RTT full_sz smpls:         1
      RTT full_sz min:        60.0 ms        RTT full_sz min:         0.0 ms
      RTT full_sz max:        70.1 ms        RTT full_sz max:         0.0 ms
      RTT full_sz avg:        65.1 ms        RTT full_sz avg:         0.0 ms
      RTT full_sz stdev:       0.0 ms        RTT full_sz stdev:       0.0 ms

      post-loss acks:            0           post-loss acks:           16
      segs cum acked:            0           segs cum acked:         2090
      duplicate acks:            0           duplicate acks:          201
      triple dupacks:            0           triple dupacks:            8
      max # retrans:             0           max # retrans:             0
      min retr time:           0.0 ms        min retr time:           0.0 ms
      max retr time:           0.0 ms        max retr time:           0.0 ms
      avg retr time:           0.0 ms        avg retr time:           0.0 ms
      sdv retr time:           0.0 ms        sdv retr time:           0.0 ms
```

**A few updates**
I tried a few other things.

- First I tried "rerouting" the flow by tunneling the transfer through a third host -- I achieved very respectable thoughput for about 30 minutes and then the throughput decayed by a factor of 20-ish to more or less match the original flow.
- Second I ran mtr from B->A with packets of size 1400b, and saw the following:

```
    X.X.X       (0.0.0.0)                                                                        Mon May 27 19:20:37 2013
    Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                                                                 Packets               Pings
     Host                                                                      Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
     1. X-X-X.X.X                                                               0.0%   173    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.0
     2. X-X.X.X-X.X.atlas.cogentco.com                                          0.0%   173    0.9   0.9   0.8   4.2   0.3
     3. X-X.X.X-X.X.atlas.cogentco.com                                          0.0%   173    0.7  12.7   0.7 211.8  38.3
     4. te7-3.ccr01.ord07.atlas.cogentco.com                                    0.0%   173    1.1  12.8   0.7 196.8  39.9
     5. te0-4-0-7.mpd21.ord01.atlas.cogentco.com                                0.0%   173    1.0   1.0   0.9   1.5   0.1
     6. be2006.ccr21.ord03.atlas.cogentco.com                                   0.0%   173    1.3   1.3   1.2   1.9   0.1
     7. be-202-pe04.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net                             0.0%   172   39.7  41.6  36.3 156.7  15.4
     8. he-3-2-0-0-cr01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net                         2.3%   172   46.9  45.0  36.8  51.4   3.6
        he-3-1-0-0-cr01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net
        he-3-0-0-0-cr01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net
        he-3-12-0-0-cr01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net
     9. he-3-6-0-0-ar01.woburn.ma.boston.comcast.net                            1.2%   172   68.7  67.9  64.8  72.4   1.6
    10. X.X.X.X.boston.comcast.net                                              1.7%   172   67.6  66.8  64.2  70.4   1.0
    11. X.X.X.X.boston.comcast.net                                              1.2%   172   67.5  66.4  64.0  69.2   1.0
    12. X.X.X.X.comcast.net                                                     1.2%   172   75.7  75.2  72.0  85.8   1.9
```

Given the results of my first experiment, and the fact that so much packet loss is occurring between two routers controlled by Comcast in a Tier III facility (350 Cermak) -- I'm starting to lean more towards the "Comcast Boogeyman" explanation.

Comment: Run a traceroute.  you may be surprised how many routers there are in between your two servers.  One or more of them will be the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a few things:

- Check for packet loss with ping. Try at least 100 pings with different packet sizes, including a larger packet around 1400 bytes.
- Round trip time (RTT) of ~70 ms could be quite high depending on distance. Maybe sure to look at a traceroute going each way. In the output you pasted, it appears that your traffic from a -> b is suffering from latency but not the other way around, which could suggest that there is a problem with the path from a -> b, but that the return path from b -> a is fine.
- Look at the techniques in [this old paper](http://qlogic.force.com/SupportCenter/servlet/fileField?id=0BE80000000Caco) for analysing TCP throughput.

The paper is a little out of date (Ethereal is now Wireshark), but the techniques are still sound.

5 seconds of idle time compared to 18 seconds of wall clock time could suggest the connection going idle when a TCP window buffer (either send or receive) is getting full, which would contribute to poor throughput. However, the very asymmetric latency is the first thing that stands out, so I would focus on that first. Good luck and thanks for introducing me to tcptrace; I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Awesome -- thanks for the pointers!  I'll give all of those try and report back.

Comment: The paper James suggested is great.  The TL;DR: try to collect the pcap at B, and then look at the various TCP StreamGraphs in Wireshark